# Unable to centre div menu

Tags: css, menu, margins

I'm having issues centring a menu, I need it to be fixed bottom centre, 20px from bottom. I've tried loads of different solutions I've found online but can't seem to get it quite right.

Here's where I'm at now http://ahdecor8.co.uk/menu/

Thank you in advance for your help! :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! That looks great! Please add some code.

Answer (score 3):

Apply `left:0` and `right:0` on your CSS.

```
#bottom_nav {
width: 1080px;
position: fixed;
bottom: 20px;
text-align: center;
z-index: 9999;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

Comment: You completely total amazing legend, thank you. This worked perfectly straight away. Could you tell me why it works? :)

Comment: fixed positions need to have at-least one left or right position. In your case you didn't given anything. so it is automatically taken `left:0;` Second thing is if you given both `left:0;` and `right:0` then it will stretch the base 100% and then try to align it center.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the menu at fixed position, try adding:

```
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

To `#bottom_nav`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to apply next css to your `<menu id="bottom_nav">`:

*** Though without `padding: 0;` it wouldn't be at the actual center.

```css
margin-left: -540px;
left: 50%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use css for menu:

```
#bottom_nav {
left: 50%;
margin-left: -540px;
padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to set the `padding` to 0. Try adding this:

```
#bottom_nav {
padding: 0;
position: fixed;
bottom: 20px;
left: calc(50% - 540px);
}
```